# How to make react-native use the hosts file in Mac OS X El Capitan?

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

I've added a new entry in my `/etc/hosts` file and its not reflecting in the IOS Simulator. I'm using OS X El Capitan. This is my hosts file

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

192.168.10.10   homestead.app
```

I can access `homestead.app` from the simulator's Safari web browser but I cannot access from my `react-native` app. I have tried restarting simulator, restarting Mac, resetting the simulator settings but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Simulator is a separate userspace running on the host macOS kernel. All networking is handled by the kernel, so there is nothing special about the Simulator per-se. If Safari in the Simulator can resolve the host then it is working. The problem may be somewhere in your app, the app transport policy blocking a non-SSL connection, or if you are serving with a self-generated cert it could be a trust issue.

Comment: you're right, its blocking non-ssl connections. i've [disabled transport security](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/) to fix this problem

Comment: Great! For testing SSL you can generate a self-signed certificate and add it to the trusted certs, then host your local app using that cert.